# ZF2, class implementing FactoryInterface pass ServiceLocator instance as attribute

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a factory that implements `FactoryInterface`, like:

```
class SomeFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        // the code to create SomeClass instance
    }
}
```

Now, all the code is inside the `createService` method (multiple `if`s, some queries, etc.) which makes the method long and difficult to follow. I'd like to refactor the code by extracting the some pieces of code into separate methods. Problem is for my case, I end up passing the instance of `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()` in each of these methods, which is no problem really, but feels ugly.

I was wondering if there's an elegant way of maybe assigning the attribute of `SomeFactory` `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()` than just passing it in every extracted method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't really understand Factories usage.

A factory is ONLY used to inject dependencies in another object, like a `Controller` or a `Service`.

So, sure, it depends of what you want to do, but I think you want to create a `Service` to do some think.

Example :

```
class MyService implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait; // used to inject SL getter and setter in your code

    public function myMethod1()
    {
        $formElementManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('formElementManager');
        // ... etc ...
    }

    public function myMethod9999() ......
}

class MyServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $myService = new MyService();

        $myService->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
        $myService->setAnotherProperty(...);

        return $myService;
    }
}
```

If `ServiceLocator` is really needed in your `MyService()` class, it's recommended to inject it in the `__construct()` method

Comment: with multiple `if`s, for example, i'm preparing the needed objects for injection. so should the `if`s really go into the service?

Comment: @DimaDz It depends of what you expect. Provide an exemple of what you want to achieve and how you construct your application. Typically, a Service can be used in a Controller.